# Происхождение топонима Анапа

Tags: топонимика

Айя-Напа (Кипр) и Анапа (Краснодарский край) города – тезки или просто созвучные топонимы?

Кажется странным, что среди множества версий происхождения топонима Анапа: 
http://www.anapacity.com/anapa-proshloe-nastoyaschee/nazvanie-anapa.html, - не нашлось места для греческой.

Answer (score 2):

Греческое происхождение этого топонима упоминается в других местах, [например](http://anapa-booking.ru/index.php/informatsiya/istoriya-anapy):

> «Ана-па» с древнегреческого переводится «высокий мыс». В «Аргонавтике»
> Аполлония Родосского название города упоминается именно в контексте с
> географическими особенностями обрывистого берега.

Впрочем, и она ничего общего не имеет с этимологией Айя-Напы, судя по всему.